# App cannot run on Android L with LogCat Error Message

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've updated my Nexus 7 (2013) to Android L preview, and found that one of my apps cannot be launched anymore with the following LogCat Error msg:

> E/WindowState(643): getStack: Window{33f867f8 u0
>   Starting com.xxxxxx.ooooo} couldn't find taskId=151
>   Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:730
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:273
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:254
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:550

Also note that the app launch animation would be played but then the screen would go back to the previous screen without any user facing error message, so I've only got this error dialog to go on and am hopelessly lost atm. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit:**
VLC and a few video players that may have used VLC library have the same issue, so I am guessing it's something with VLC's native library given how Android L has tightened up JNI a bit, but I am lost at to where to start modifying given the opaque log message :-/

Comment: For me it was because I was calling `syncState()` on an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` with a `null` `DrawerLayout` attached to it. Not sure why yours is failing, maybe debug the code and paste the lines of code that are suspect.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @user25 sorry, don't remember how it was resolved, it might have fixed itself on Lollipop production version.